# Clipboard Event

Tags: javascript, html

I'm faced a problem with creating a ClipboardEvent from code. clipboardData object in created event not defined.

May be somebody know something about it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="testPasteInput">
    <button onclick="pasteFromCode()">Paste</button>
    <script>
        const testPasteInput = document.getElementById('testPasteInput');
        testPasteInput.addEventListener('paste', ({clipboardData}) => console.log(clipboardData.getData('text')));

        function pasteFromCode() {
            const clipboardEvent = new ClipboardEvent('paste', { dataType: 'text/plain', data: '123' });
            testPasteInput.dispatchEvent(clipboardEvent);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why aren't you just setting the value?

Comment: @baao it's only example. I have one case when I need to dispatch ClipboardEvent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a browser specific issue. Your code works fine in **Firefox**, but `clipboardData` is not being set correctly in webkit browsers like **Chrome** and **Safari**.

I have created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hanqw4k/) with your code, which can be tested in Firefox to verify that it is working there.

Actually `ClipboardEvent` is an experimental technology, which is not yet fully supported by all the major browsers. The usage of event creation using the **constructor**(like `new ClipboardEvent('paste')`) itself is not yet supported in Internet Explorer. Tthe same can be verified from the image below from [MDN-documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) for browser compatibility

[image]

But, **Chrome** has provided support for the all three, and therefore it is their bug. I have reported a bug [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=800742) in Chrome bug report dashboard for the same. Hopefully they will pick it up and fix the issue in any of their upcoming releases.