# ClipboardEvent undefined in IE11

Tags: angular, events, internet-explorer-11

I have the following code in one of my Angular directives:

```
  @HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  onPaste($event: ClipboardEvent) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const input = (<HTMLInputElement>$event.target);
      input.value = input.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    });
  }
```

It fails in IE11 with an error saying that `ClipboardEvent is undefined`.
Luckily I could type it to just `Event`, but I am wondering why it breaks -
is there any lib that I could add in angular-cli.json to make it work with `ClipboardEvent`?

```
"lib": [
  "es2017",
  "dom"
],
```

"dom" is where `Event` comes from...

Comment: It's especially weird considering ClipboardEvent isn't even available at runtime. It's a type annotation. IE11 must be analyzing the typescript via the source map somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this

```
@HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  onPaste($event) {
    var clipboardData; 
    if (window['clipboardData']) { // IE 
       clipboardData = window['clipboardData']; 
    } else if ($event.originalEvent.clipboardData && $event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData) { // other browsers 
       clipboardData = $event.originalEvent.clipboardData; }
    }}
```

Clipboard event still under experimental technology. This will work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an issue in IE with angulars JIT (Just-In-Time compilation) build mode. It helped to use AOT (Ahead-Of-Time). Then there's no error loading the site.

```
ng build --aot
```

JIT makes the browser compile the code on runtime and IE seems to not compile correctly (that's guessing!).
Here's the explaination of difference bewteen AOT and JIT: 
https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Note: 
Paste from clipboard does still not work in IE, though. Here is well explained why it's not working everywhere: [Clipboard Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186920/clipboard-event/48189574) (Stack Overflow)